# How to compare two 2d arrays of char in C/ C++

Tags: c++, c, string, multidimensional-array, char

I am passing two 2d arrays of char into a function, that will return 1 if the arrays are equal and 0 otherwise.
size of the arrays is [4][4], However when I try to iterate through the array I get an error.

```
int checkIfWin(char** array, char** array2){

int winner = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    if(strcmp(array2[i], array[i])==0){
        winner = 1;
    }
    else
        winner = 0;

}
return winner;

}
```

UPDATE:

The reason why I was getting an errorn while strcmp is because I did not malloc the second 2d array.

Comment: The simple solution is to use two for loops (one nested in the other).

Comment: @Maciej Girek how exactly does the user win? please clarify what you want.

Comment: Detail: Code in _not_ passing a 2D array to `checkIfWin(char** array, ...)`.  It is passing a pointer to a pointer nor is that calling code shown.  If the calling code was `char a[4][4]; ... checkIfWin(a, ...);` there is a type mis-match.  Post the calling code.

Comment: 1) There is no language C/C++. C and C++ are different languages. Remove the unrelated tag. 2) provide a [mcve]. 3) `char **` is **not** a 2D array, nor can it point to one.

Comment: Show the code that calls the function, including how you set up the arguments. (Preferably a MCVE)

Answer (score 2):

`char[]` is different from `char *`, the first places the value `'\0'` at the end of the array instead the second does not.

The function **strcmp** will compare the elements until it finds the value `'\0'`, for that task better compare element to element and if you find a difference returns automatically.

```
int checkIfWin(char** array, char** array2){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            if(array2[i][j] != array[i][j]){
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: In this case, I am pretty sure the user wants to match to match between the arrays, not loop through the second array against each 1st for a winner.

Comment: Please ask the user to make sure

Comment: That break statement will only break out of the inner loop.  You want to break out of the outer loop as well if winner = 0.

Comment: It is not necessary to do it since it defaults to 1, please analyze the answer better.

Comment: Immediately `return 0` is certainly more efficient - yet functionally the same.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using strncmp():

```
   int winner = 1, i;

   for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

      if((strncmp(array2[i], array[i], 4)) != 0){
         winner = 0;
         break;
      }
   }

 return winner;
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this solution is a bad solution?

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. You should explain what you changed and why you made those changes.